# Is it possible to give more memory to an object in Swift or Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I find that UITextView's become sluggish when you add more than 1MB of text. Outside of complex custom work, such as re-creating UITextView, is it possible to somehow allocate more memory or some other trick to an object?

Comment: _1MB of text_ sounds a vague description to me, please share some code and a sample snippet of the text and its encoding

Answer (score 5):

Allocating more memory to UITextView isn't going to help you. It's already taking all the memory it wants. If there were a simple trick with no tradeoffs, then UITextView would almost certainly just do that automatically. So it depends on what tradeoffs you want and what features you're using. For instance, you may get some improvements by removing features like data detectors. Or using only unformatted strings (rather than attributed strings with complex formatting). Not allowing editing may improve things. Of course if you need those features, then that's not helpful (but you haven't explained what you're doing). If you're implementing delegate methods, then of course the problem could certainly be in your methods rather than UITextView. I somewhat doubt these tweaks are going to change a lot, but turning off features is the best place to start.

1MB does seem like a lot of text for a UITextView. It's not really its common use case and opens up some difficult layout issues, especially if there is any formatting going on. It also represents a difficult user experience for navigating (does your scrollbar really work effectively on a 500 page document?) I'd almost certainly be looking at a custom solution (possibly built on TextKit) to take care of this fairly custom problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a text editor on iOS, and every now and then someone loads a book or something, and the app gets sluggish, and at times, it freezes, requiring a hard restart of the device.